# SoapUI 4.6.4 error: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL

Tags: web-services, wsdl, soapui

I am trying to add a `New SOAP Project` in SoapUI 4.6.4. When I create a new soap project and type the Initial WSDL url: http://xx.xxx.x.xxx/Structure/DataEx?wsdl, I get the following error.

> Error loading [http://xx.xxx.x.xxx/Structure/DataEx?wsdl]: 
>   org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException: java.io.IOException: Server returned
>   HTTP response code: 401 for URL:
>   http://xx.xxx.x.xxx/Structure/DataEx?wsdl

When I access the URL via a browser, it prompts me to enter username and password. After I enter that information, I am able to access the WSDL. I looked at the request header and the authorization of type Digest.

My question is, where in SoapUI 4.6.4 do I get to enter the authentication/authorization information so that I can get the WSDL into SoapUI.

Comment: The easiest option would be to download it locally and then import it. But it may be an issue if the definition changes frequently and need to update it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a [bug in the 4.6.4 version](http://forum.soapui.org/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=22818#p52356) but was solved in the maintenance  build which is available @  http://www.soapui.org/Downloads/soapui-pro-nightly-builds.html

This information is available on soapUI form where a user asked the [same question](http://forum.soapui.org/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=22818).

Additionally, to handle authentication in your subsequent service requests you should check out [soapUI's guide on the same](http://www.soapui.org/SOAP-and-WSDL/authenticating-soap-requests.html).